# WordPress have div change text every 7 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, date

I'm using wordpress and have a div where I've added some text. I have the code below that changes the text every two seconds, but my end result is I want the text changed every 7 days (or every Sunday, whatever is easier).

```
var names = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'];

setInterval(function() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = names[rand];
}, 2000);
```

So my two issues with this code are:

- Every time the page loads it always loads the text that is initially set then changes every 2 seconds
- It needs to be changed to update once every 7 days. Meaning on page load the text should always be the same until it's been up for 7 days

Any idea on how to accomplish that?

Comment: does the randomness matter or can you simply cycle through the array

Comment: @Jorg random is fine

Comment: random is harder actually. otherwise you could go by `names[weeknumber % names.length]` and be done with it

Comment: @Jorg Yeah I was about to edit my comment. If it's easier to cycle, then that.

Comment: would this do it? https://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/Lmv924uo/

Comment: Instead of javascript, why don't you use server side `wp_cron`?

Comment: @Jorg that appears to do the trick! Thank you, I appreciate it. Time to dissect it now.

Comment: @Jorg working off your code, could I be able to alter it to have a div display 5 names from the array and have all of them change every 5 seconds?

Comment: That would be going back to your old code, with the interval.

Comment: Hi @Jorg, is this close? https://jsfiddle.net/Lmv924uo/4/ - I know it's wrong but I am wondering if I am going in the right direction. I also want to make sure it doesn't show two of the same values.

Comment: you were. avoiding duplicates is easiest if the array is randomized, that way you don't have to keep track of which indexes you've already picked: https://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/Lmv924uo/

Comment: @Jorg Cool, that makes sense. One more question - https://jsfiddle.net/Lmv924uo/13/ - I am trying to add one comment in each div so I can style each one, what am I missing? How do I make it so one values goes in one div?

Comment: i'd create div's on the fly: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmv924uo/14/

Comment: @Jorg Okay, thanks, it's working, but there is an issue. I am trying to have 5 divs populated when the page loads that update every 5 minutes; so, not that every page load another 5 load, but the same 5 quotes stay put for 5 minutes, then swap. Plugging in your code waits 'x' seconds, then populated and then swaps every 'x' second. Basically trying to initialize 5 quotes that rotate every 5 minutes.

Comment: that's not possible without persisting the quotes you're displaying, as people can go to new pages which would re-load your quotes. if quotes only exist in the browser, you could look into storing them in localStorage, or call a webservice every 5 minutes that gives you new quotes. I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: @Jorg okay, with what you provided, is there a way to make the quotes/divs appear immediately then not change for 5 minutes? That way every page load a random set of 5 quotes would appear?